# Error. How to modify the downloadURL in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am creating a function to upload profile pic into Firebase. However, I am having problem with the download URL. The error **Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'**.
Please be advised on how to modify this block of code. As Users class I have a signature as " uid, username, email and profilePicLink.

```swift
func uploadProfilePic(profileImage:UIImage){
       var dataBaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        let profileImageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profileImages")
            .child("\(NSUUID().uuidString). jpg")
        if let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75){
            profileImageRef.putData(imageData,metadata:nil)
            {
                metadata, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                } else {
                    print(metadata!)
                    if let downloadUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
                        if (self.profilePicLink == ""){
                            self.profilePicLink = downloadUrl
                            Database.dataBaseRef.child("users").child(self.uid).updateChildValues(["profilePicLink": downloadUrl])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that your `metadata` variable, which is a [StorageMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata) type object, doesn't have a method call `downloadURL()`.

If you want to get a download URL, you should follow the instructions in the Firebase documentation for [generating a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url).  You can see there that downloadURL() is a method on StorageReference.  Your reference is in `profileImageRef`, so you will need to call [downloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#downloadurlcompletion:) on that instead.